# data submit even when cancel button is pressed in sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sweetalert2

I was able to  send data when the confirm button pressed.
however, when the **cancel button pressed** sweetalert2 shows as it **successfully inserted the data.**
back-end shows as it a empty string.(in the database table)
how to validate when I pressed the cancel button, not to send data to the back-end.

---

## Javascript function

```
    function inputPass(complaintID) { // complaint id pass is ok.
    swal({
        text: 'Input comment message',
        input: 'textarea',
        showCancelButton: true,
    }).then(function(sample_text) { 
        console.log(sample_text);
        if(sample_text === '') { // problem is here.
            swal({
                type: 'warning',
                html: 'cannot proceed without input'
            });
        } else {
            console.log(sample_text);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../ajax/ajax_active_deact.php?type=complaint_answered",
                data: {complaintID: complaintID, sampleText: sample_text}
            }).done(function (res) {
                if(!res) {
                    swal({
                        type: 'error',
                        html: 'insert the valid text'
                    });
                } else {
                    swal({
                        title: 'done',
                        text: 'all right',
                        type: 'success',
                        allowOutsideClick: false,
                        confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

### php ajax code

```
function complaint_answered() {
    include_once('../backend/ConsumerComplaint.php');
    $con_complaint = new ConsumerComplaint();
    $res = $con_complaint>mark_as_answered($_POST['complaintID'],$_POST['sampleText']);
    echo $res;
}
```

---

### This is my class function

```
    function mark_as_answered($id, $comment) {
    //var_dump($comment);
    $val = $comment['value']; // $comment is a associative array, with the key of 'value'
    $sql = "UPDATE c_consumer_complaint SET `status` = 'answered', `update` = '$val' 
            WHERE  complaint_id = '$id' ";
    $res = $this->conn->query($sql);
    return $res;
}
```

---

- image of when i pressed cancel button in network panel in chrome
  [image]

---

- image of the console
  [image]

---

- image of the post data in chrome
  [image]

I'm new to development and can't get around how to solve this issue.
please can anyone give me what I'm doing wrong here.
Thnks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get the `result.value` if the user clicked on Ok so you can check if there is a value and if it is empty you show your error message. If there is no value nothing happens.

**Snippet:**

```js
    swal({
        text: 'Input comment message',
        input: 'textarea',
        showCancelButton: true,
    }).then(function(result) {
        if(result.value) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../ajax/ajax_active_deact.php?type=complaint_answered",
                data: {complaintID: complaintID, sampleText: result.value}
            }).done(function (res) {
                if(!res) {
                    swal({
                        type: 'error',
                        html: 'insert the valid text'
                    });
                } else {
                    swal({
                        title: 'done',
                        text: 'all right',
                        type: 'success',
                        allowOutsideClick: false,
                        confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
                    });
                }
            });
        } else if (result.value === "") {
            swal({
                type: 'warning',
                html: 'cannot proceed without input'
            });
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.28.7/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```

**Your Class:**

In your **php ajax code** you are passing the `$_POST['sampleText']` which is not an array but a string so `$comment['value']` will not contain the text.

```
function mark_as_answered($id, $comment) {
    //var_dump($comment);
    $val = $comment;
    $sql = "UPDATE c_consumer_complaint SET `status` = 'answered', `update` = '$val' 
            WHERE  complaint_id = '$id' ";
    $res = $this->conn->query($sql);
    return $res;
}
```

PS: Please educate yourself on [SQL-Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) so people cant inject harmful code into your SQL-Queries.

Comment: code works, but still some issue. when I enter some text to the textarea, in the database table only shows "one character".... even though my table "update" field data type is "text" type.

Comment: I updated my answer, I think you have a mistake in your `mark_as_answered()` method.

Comment: -> this is error I get from the backend Warning: **Illegal string offset 'value'** in C:\wamp64\www\PDMS\backend\ConsumerComplaint.php on line 151

Comment: You save my day Oh! man. Thank you very much. It works like a charm.

Comment: I added a part about sql-injection into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like sample text is always set to an array. I would try changing the if statement

```
if(sample_text === '') { // problem is here.
            swal({
                type: 'warning',
                html: 'cannot proceed without input'
            });
        } else {
            console.log(sample_text);
```

to something like

```
if(sample_text['dismiss'] == 'cancel') { // problem is here.
        swal({
            type: 'warning',
            html: 'cannot proceed without input'
        });
    } else {
        console.log(sample_text);
```

Comment: still has the same issue. data pass even when I changed to your code suggestion.